# Fade In Div on Page load after a 2 second delay not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element that I want to fade in after a 2 second delay on page load. I am trying to use javascript/jquery to try and do this. However, it's not working and the div doesn't fade in whatsoever.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

```
<div class="cookies_not one"></div>

<script>
    $(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
  $('.cookies_not').fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>
```

Styles

```
.cookies_not {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background: rgba(45, 45, 45, 1);
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 990;
    display:none;

}
```

Comment: Make sure that you imported jquery in your html file

Comment: is there an error in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  
    $("#div4").delay(2000).fadeIn();
});
    

</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="div4" style="width:90px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:purple;"></div><br>

</body>
</html>
```

do make sure you imported jquery link to your webpage and there is no error related to jquery on console.

Comment: excellent thank you. I wasn't importing jquery properly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()`:

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(()=>{
  $('.cookies_not').fadeIn('slow');
}, 2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without jQuery:

```js
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      document.querySelector('.cookies_not').classList.add("loaded");
    }, 2000); 
  });
```

```css
.cookies_not {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background: rgba(45, 45, 45, 1);
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 990;
    display: none;
}

.loaded {
  animation: 1s myanimation;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes myanimation {
    0%   {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="cookies_not one"></div>
```